# Creating xml from MySQL query with Python and lxml

Tags: python, mysql, xml, parsing, lxml

I am trying to use Python and LXML to create an XML file from a Mysql query result. Here is the format I want.

```
     <DATA>
         <ROW>
             <FIELD1>content</FIELD1>
             <FIELD2>content</FIELD2>
         </ROW>
    </DATA>
```

For some reason the code isn't formatting right and the XML will not validate. Here is that code

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import tostring
from lxml.builder import E
import MySQLdb


try:
       conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'host',user = 'user',passwd = 'pass',db = 'db')
       cursor = conn.cursor()
except:
       sys.exit(1)

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM db.table")
columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
allRows = cursor.fetchall()
xmlFile = open("mysqlxml.xml","w")
xmlFile.write('<DATA>')
for rows in allRows:
       xmlFile.write('<ROW>')
       columnNumber = 0
       for column in columns:
              data = rows[columnNumber]
              if data == None:
                     data = ''
              xmlFile.write('<%s>%s</%s>' % (column,data,column))
              columnNumber += 1
       xmlFile.write('</ROW>')
xmlFile.write('</DATA>')
xmlFile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little example of how you can build xml using lxml.

It's useful to create a helper function for element creation, here's a simple one. I've created a dummy cursor object for demo purposes.

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.builder import E as buildE

class DummyCursor(object):
  def __init__(self,fields,rows=5):
    self.description = [[f] for f in fields]
    self.data = [ ["%s%02d" % (f,i) for f in fields] for i in range(rows) ]
  def fetchall(self):
    return self.data

def E(tag,parent=None,content=None):
  """Simple E helper"""
  element = buildE(tag)
  if content is not None:
    element.text = unicode(content)
  if parent is not None:
    parent.append(element)
  return element

def fetchXML(cursor):
  fields = [x[0] for x in cursor.description ]
  doc = E('data')
  for record in cursor.fetchall():
    r = E('row',parent=doc)
    for (k,v) in zip(fields,record):
      E(k,content=v,parent=r)
  return doc

doc = fetchXML(DummyCursor(['name','description']))

print etree.tostring(doc,pretty_print=True)
```

Yields:

```
<data>
  <row>
    <name>name00</name>
    <description>description00</description>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>name01</name>
    <description>description01</description>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>name02</name>
    <description>description02</description>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>name03</name>
    <description>description03</description>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>name04</name>
    <description>description04</description>
  </row>
</data>
```

Comment: I am having trouble porting your example over to mine. Specifically putting the content into the tags

Comment: I've not got mysql handy. If each row returned by `fetchall` is anything other than a sequence of values, then you'll need to turn the row into a sequence of values. Also you may need to flesh out the E helper class to render non string content values to strings

Comment: I've modified the helper to unicode the content parameter passed. You might, for example want to represent booleans as lowercase depending on the schema, so you could change the helper to render boolean values to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Create or Update XML from MySQL query with Python and lxml, in a AWS s3 bucket.

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import json, pymysql, requests
import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer


BD = 'bd'
HOST = 'host'
USER = 'user'
PASS = 'pass'

HEADERS = {"Content-Type" : "application/json"}
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'value_access_key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'value_sercret_access_key'

def updateXMLFunction():

    db = pymysql.connect(HOST,USER,PASS,BD)     
    cursor = db.cursor()

    SQL = "SELECT * FROM table_name"

    cursor.execute(SQL)

    resp = {  
        "response": {
            "message" : "",
            "estatus" : "",
        }  
    }

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
         aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
         aws_secret_access_key= AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    bucket = s3.Bucket('name_carpet_bucket')
    object = bucket.Object('filename_heresavetheresult.xml')

    columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
    allRows = cursor.fetchall()

    Document = ElementTree.Element("Document")
    try:
        for rows in allRows:
            Row = ElementTree.SubElement(Document, "Row")
            columnNumber = 0
            for column in columns:

                data = rows[columnNumber]
                if data == None:
                    data = ''
                data = str(data).replace('&', '\&')
                columnas = ('<%s>%s</%s>' % (column,data,column))   
                ElementTree.SubElement(Row, column).text = data
                columnNumber += 1

        xmlstr = ElementTree.tostring(Document, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
        # print(xmlstr)
        object.put(Body=xmlstr, ACL='public-read')

        resp["response"]["message"] = "Se ha creado el XML correctamente"
        resp["response"]["estatus"] = "updated"

        print(json.dumps(resp, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
        return resp

    except Exception as e:
        resp["response"]["message"] = e
        resp["response"]["estatus"] = "error"
        # print(json.dumps(resp, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
        return resp

updateXMLFunction()
```