# Python export MySQL SELECT to XML

Tags: python, mysql, xml

I am trying to work out how to export the result of a MySQL SELECT query to an XML file. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT id, extension_id, flow, filename, filesize, unread, cr_date, callerid, 
  length, callid, info, party
FROM extension_recording
```

I can see that there are two ways of going about this - either running mysqldump --xml or using Python's XML modules. Not sure which is the best way to go about this, interested to hear some opinions on which might work better?

Thanks

Comment: As `mysqldump` is written in C and compiled, it will be much faster than any python-based solution.

Comment: Why do you need it in first place? I guess if XML does not solve your problem, you are not using enough of it :(

Comment: @thg435 - will it still be fast if I call it from Python?

Comment: @mvp I'm writing a Python app to archive a bunch of call recordings, and delete the records from the DB. I want to include an XML file in the tar file so that there's a record of what was in the DB before the records were deleted - an index really.

Comment: Look at this article. Maybe it is useful for you.

[Creating xml from MySQL query with Python and lxml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012192/creating-xml-from-mysql-query-with-python-and-lxml)

Comment: You can simply create SQL dump of your data. It will be much smaller compared to XML, and very easy and fast to load into db again if you need to process it elsewhere. If you dump it properly, you can even load it into SQLite and have fast access to your data on mobile device

Comment: @mvp yes maybe that would be better. Thinking about this some more though, I only need to dump a subset of the data in the table. My Python app has an array which contains the filenames and paths of the recordings that have been archived, the DB dump (either XML or native MySQL) needs to only include those records. Using Python & XML I can just add to the file on each iteration of the loop that archives the files. Can't think how to do this using mysqldump.